# Why catch an exception just to throw it again?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, exception

In a webservice I see this code:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function dosomething() As Boolean
    Try
        If successful Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

What's the point of catching the exception and just throwing it again? Do I miss something?

Edit:
Thanks for the answers! I thought it was something like that, but wasn't sure if I could/would refactor those away without any implications.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can think of no reason to do this for functionality. However, it can arise when previously  there was some error handling (logging usually) that has been removed, and the developer removed the log handling but did not restructure the code to remove the redundant try/catch.

Answer (score 47):

**Don't do this.**

If you absolutely need to rethrow the exception, just use `throw;` using `throw ex;` erases the stack trace and is absolutely wrong.

Comment: Which is another reason why I would wrap it as an inner exception if I needed to do this for logging.

Comment: Why? Just throw the original exception. Logging should not change or alter anything.

Comment: To add my own semantics to the exception.  Ex. I get a SqlException because I attempt to insert a row with a duplicate primary key.  In my method I know what kind of object and what key value is being inserted.  I can write a better exception message yet still retain all the information.

Comment: This has nothing to do with logging then. Different concept.

Answer (score 5):

Probably a bit of code left over from debugging (you'd set a breakpoint on the throw so you could examine the exception in the debugger).  I might do something like this if I wanted to log the exception and then pass it up the chain, although I'd probably wrap the exception in another one with a more meaningful (to my application) error message.

Answer (score 5):

One of the architectures [(design patterns)](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/20/custom-exceptions-when-should-you-create-them.aspx) I could see this being used in is where a transaction is being handled. The function does its work, fails, and the catch block completes the transaction to a known state (usually a roll back) and then throws a user-defined exception.

As it stands now, refactor that code to a more sane state.

Comment: Exactly the pattern I have seen as well

Answer (score 1):

Not only is the try/catch pointless, but so is the IF. The whole function could be reduced to one line:

```
return successful
```

At which point, why bother? Why not just test "successful" instead of calling the function?

Well, okay, it's a Web Method, I guess you need the function just to give Ajax or whomever a handle.

(Yes, I'm aware my answer is 7 years late. I just stumbled across this when searching for something entirely unrelated.)

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft's CodeAnalysis: (CA2200: Rethrow to preserve stack details)

"Once an exception is thrown, part of the information it carries is the stack trace. The stack trace is a list of the method call hierarchy that starts with the method that throws the exception and ends with the method that catches the exception. If an exception is re-thrown by specifying the exception in the throw statement, the stack trace is restarted at the current method and the list of method calls between the original method that threw the exception and the current method is lost. To keep the original stack trace information with the exception, use the throw statement without specifying the exception."

```
  Sub CatchAndRethrowImplicitly()
     Try
        ThrowException()
     Catch e As ArithmeticException
        ' Satisfies the rule.
        Throw
     End Try
  End Sub
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2200-rethrow-to-preserve-stack-details?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for Monitor makes this very likely to rethrow an error as you need a finally to ensure Monitor.Exit is called

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Dim lockObj As New Object()

If Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj) Then
    Try
        ' The critical section.
    Catch
       throw
    Finally
       ' Ensure that the lock is released.
       Monitor.Exit(lockObj)
    End Try
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There are extremely good reasons to do this, especially in a Full Stack/N Tier environment.

It would make sense to Try/Catch your code in your class library, log the exception and throw it back to the calling application to allow for the caller to handle exceptions the way it wants to.

Remember, in a Full Stack environment, the stacks should be independent and not know of each other's inner functionalities, likewise, they should not assume to know the way a Stack, outside itself, would like to handle exceptions that are caught.  Handling an exception realtime and then passing it to the caller is a very helpful thing to do.

And always use just "Throw", not "Throw ex".  Throw will rethrow the handles exception keeping it's stack intact.

Answer (score -9):

You may want to do it if you want to catch an exception except a sub-class of it.

For example,

```
try {
    // Something stupid
}
catch(RuntimeException e) {
    throw e; //Handle it outside
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // I'm dead
}
```

Comment: But you still don't want to call "throw e".  You want "throw" instead.  Calling "throw e" drops the stack information up to that point, and it is dangerous.

Comment: WRONG WRONG WRONG. PLEASE DONT TELL PEOPLE THIS.

Comment: The throw e; is obviously wrong but aside from that this is an interesting idea. Not sure if there is a use case for it though....

Comment: And you also swallowed the general Exception so nobody knows about it.

Comment: @Quarrelsome: No, just wrong. There is no wisdom or knowledge to be gained from this.

Comment: @Rich B - I agree, but rather than just saying 'It's WRONG', why not provide some constructive feedback of why it's wrong so others can learn from it. I know a comment doesn't leave much room, but you could try...

Comment: There IS some wisdom to be gained here.  It is completely reasonable to catch a specific exception subclass, in order handle it appropriately, but to generically catch the general exception, which represents cases you can't handle, but will log instead.  Agreed destroying the stack is bad though.

Comment: @Mike: No need. It should just be deleted or voted into oblivion.

Comment: n Java, It WON'T DESTROY the stack. It kept all information from the original throw.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the "vb.net" tag on the question